# wp_insert_post() fails when SuperUser

Tags: wordpress

I use the following code in a plugin to add posts to a WordPress MU System. Everything works fine unless a Superuser tries to use the function. The function returns

> Could not insert post into the database

```
$post = [
            'post_content' => NULL,
            'post_title' => $title,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'artikelregister',
            'tags_input' => $keywords,
            'tax_input' => [
                'issue' => $issue,
                'keywords' => $keywords
            ]
        ];
$insert = wp_insert_post($post);
```

The Superuser is assigned to the page we're working in. I have no idea

---

Edit: Correct error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding no solution, I built a workaround:

I inserted an extra form field named 'insert_user' which values are the IDs of users.

```
if(isset($_POST['insert_user']) && is_numeric($_POST['insert_user']) && is_super_admin()) {
            $postAuthor = $_POST['insert_user'];
        } else {
            $postAuthor = get_current_user_id();
        }
$post = [
        'post_author' => $postAuthor,
        //more arguments here ...
];
$insert = wp_insert_post($post);
```

So now the SuperUser can select which user ID is used to import.